# Shift data in multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, matrix

I'm currently facing a problem where I have to shift data in a multidimensional JS array in different directions, but I think the first solution I whipped up is not as efficient as it could be (some fancy math I don't know of maybe?).

Let me explain the problem a bit better with some examples of my data.

This is the array in question:

```
[1][0][1][0][1][0]
[0][1][1][0][0][0]
[0][0][1][0][1][1]
[0][0][0][0][1][1]
[0][0][1][1][0][0]
[1][0][0][1][1][1]
```

If I shifted it to the left, it should look like this:

```
[1][1][1][0][0][0]
[1][1][0][0][0][0]
[1][1][1][0][0][0]
[1][1][0][0][0][0]
[1][1][0][0][0][0]
[1][1][1][1][0][0]
```

Or down

```
[0][0][0][0][0][0]
[0][0][0][0][0][0]
[0][0][1][0][1][0]
[0][0][1][0][1][1]
[1][0][1][1][1][1]
[1][1][1][1][1][1]
```

To put it simple - shift **1's** as *far* as possible.

The code I wrote is fairly simple

```
for (w = 0; w < arraySize; w++) {
    for (h = 0; h < arraySize; h++) {
        tiles = $('.arrayContainer .row').eq(w).children();
        if (tiles.eq(h).html() != "" && tiles.eq(h - 1).html() == "" && (h-1) >= 0) {
            tiles.eq(h - 1).html(tiles.eq(h).html());
            tiles.eq(h).html("");
        }
    }
}
```

This will shift values left-to-right by one step. `arraySize` is the variable that determines the size of the array, `tiles` gets each row of the array output.

If I wasn't here, posting and wouldn't think this could be done better I'd create four of these structures and just live with it, but I'm pretty sure this can be done better.

Comment: Are you always dealing with just 0s and 1s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a once over:

- You should consider MVC, your data should live in an object you created, you should update your model, and then from your model update the UI
- If you dont want to do this, then you should at least find all cells and assign each cell to a 2d JS array

  ```
  var tiles = [];
  for (w = 0; w < arraySize; w++) {
      tiles[w] = [];
      for (h = 0; h < arraySize; h++) {
          tiles[w][h] = $('.arrayContainer .row').eq(w).children().eq(h);
      }
  }
  ```

  Otherwise you are executing `$('.arrayContainer .row')` far too many times, and that operation takes a lot of time, then you can do your logic like this:

  ```
  for (w = 0; w < arraySize; w++) {
      for (h = 0; h < arraySize; h++) {
          tile = tiles[w][h]
          if (tile.html() != '' && tiles[w][h-1].html() == '' && (h-1) >= 0) {
              tiles[w][h-1].html(tile.html());
              tile.html('');
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  You could consider assigning `tiles[w][h-1]` to a variable as well to make it more readable
- Consider `c` and `r` as variables ( `column` and `row` if you are feeling verbose ). Those are better names than `h`eight and `w`idth.
- I hope you declared `tiles` with `var` somewhere else, otherwise you have global namespace pollution.
- As for not having to repeat the same 2 loops for every direction, you could think about passing a columnDelta and RowDelta ( for your 2 loops, columnDelta would be -1, rowDelta would be 0 ) I am not sure it is worth it, since you only have 4 cardinal directions, up to you.

Comment: Thanks for all the great suggestions, they truly make sense. What about the for loops, though. Is there any way to avoid creating this structure for every direction I want the data to be shifted?

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!
I'll stick to these suggestions.